# Overriding nested inline styles

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a link inside of a table, but I've never actually dealt with overriding inline CSS before.

**Code**

```
<td class="playertableData">
     <a href="" content="ajax#/ffl/format/pvopop/summary?leagueId=409279&amp;positionId=4&amp;playerId=70419&amp;seasonId=2017" class="flexpop" instance="_ppc" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">
         <span style="color:green">26th</span>
     </a>
</td>
```

and there is another just like it but with `color: red`. I looked at some of the other topics on overriding but what I saw didn't cover a situation like this, at least not as I read it. Thanks in advance.

(For reference, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxE1L.png).)

Comment: Do you want to override based on logic? or just in general?

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I don't even know where to start. There's two different types, this one and another with color:green that differ based on the `playerId=` part of the URL. Those will change with any player changes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css

> **[!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)** changes the rules for override priority of css cascades.

```
.playertableData > a > span{color:red!important;}
```

---

in jQuery

```
$(".playertableData > a > span").css({ color: 'red' });
```

Comment: This works, but it turns all of them one color. There are two colors, red and green. The difference is in the `playerId=` portion of the link, and the values will change as the players/games do.

Comment: No. I recorded a quick GIF to show. The only thing that changes is the span style. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/NDRplSw.gifv)

Comment: i created sample code . try this https://jsfiddle.net/farhadB/ev3L0wt9/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **!important** like so:

```
span{
    color:red!important;
}
```